# SMS scheduler not accepting multiple alarms

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, android-broadcast

I'm developing an sms scheduler App. Here the user can set a time, number and a msg. My code works fine with just if there is just one message i need to schedule. However if i want to have multiple schedules, it wont be possible as the new one replaces the old.

The technique i'm using is creating an array of pending intents with different request codes as suggested by some other posts i read, however the new schedule replaces the old one.

**Below is my code:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zax_sms_scheduler);

        Button dateSet=(Button) findViewById(R.id.dateSetBtn);
        Button timeSet=(Button) findViewById(R.id.timeSetBtn);

        dateSet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthodyear, int dayofmonth) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mMonth=monthodyear;
                        mYear=year;
                        mDay=dayofmonth;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Date Set is :"+mDay+"/"+(mMonth+1)+"/"+mYear, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                };
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new DatePickerDialog(ZaxSmsScheduler.this,d,Calendar.YEAR,Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).show();
            }
        });

        timeSet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view2, int hour, int min) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mHour=hour;
                        mMin=min;

                        if(mHour>=12)
                            mHour=mHour-12;

                        Log.d("MYAPP", "hh:"+mHour+"\nmm:"+mMin);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Time Set is:"+mHour+":"+mMin+":00", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                };
                Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
                new TimePickerDialog(ZaxSmsScheduler.this,t,cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),true).show();

            }
        });

        Button saveAndClearBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        saveAndClearBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Calendar myCal=Calendar.getInstance();
                long timeToTrigger;
                /*myCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
                myCal.set(Calendar.MONTH,mMonth);
                myCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);*/

                myCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, mHour);
                myCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMin);
                myCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                long setTime=myCal.getTimeInMillis();

                if(setTime>System.currentTimeMillis())
                {

                    timeToTrigger=setTime-System.currentTimeMillis();
                    EditText edt1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    EditText edt2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    msg=edt2.getText().toString();
                    telno=edt1.getText().toString();

                    SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("MYDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
                    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mySmsScheduler(SlNo VARCHAR,Number VARCHAR,Msg VARCHAR);");

                    String s="INSERT INTO mySmsScheduler VALUES ('"+count+"','"+telno+"','"+msg+"');";
                    db.execSQL(s);
                    Log.d("MYREC", "Insertion of data successfull");
                    db.close();

                    edt1.setText("");
                    edt2.setText("");

                     Intent intent = new Intent();
                     intent.setClass(ZaxSmsScheduler.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
                     Bundle b = new Bundle();
                     b.putString("index", Integer.toString(count));
                     intent.putExtras(b);

                     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ZaxSmsScheduler.this, (int)Math.random(), intent, 0);
                     intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
                     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                     alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                            + timeToTrigger, intentArray.get(count));
                     count++;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms Scheduled after:"+(timeToTrigger/1000)+" sec.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.d("MYAPP", "Set Time:"+(setTime/1000)+"Sec. \n"+"Cur time:"+System.currentTimeMillis()/1000);
                    Log.d("MYAPP", "Time to trigger:"+(timeToTrigger/1000)+"sec.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Enter a valid time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance();
                    int h=calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                    int m=calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                    Log.d("MYAPP", "cur HH:"+h+"\ncur MM:"+m);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

**The code for my broadcast receiver is:**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int myCount;
    String cnt=intent.getStringExtra("index");
    if(cnt==null)
        Log.d("MYAPP","Data not received");
    Log.d("MYAPP", "Count:"+cnt);
    myCount=Integer.parseInt(cnt);

    Log.d("MYAPP","Broadcast receiver called...");
    SQLiteDatabase db=arg0.openOrCreateDatabase("MYDB",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT Number, Msg FROM mySmsScheduler WHERE SlNo=="+myCount, null);
    Log.d("MYAPP", "Cursor reference obtained...");
    if(c!=null)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    else
        Log.d("MYAPP", "cursor is null");
   /* c.moveToFirst();*/
    String num=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Number"));
    String myMsg=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Msg"));

    Log.d("MYAPP", "number:"+num+"\nMsg:"+myMsg);
    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sm.sendTextMessage(num, null, myMsg, null, null);
    Log.d("MYAPP", "Message Sent");
    Toast.makeText(arg0, "Msg sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String table="mySmsScheduler";
    String whereClause = "SlNo = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { Integer.toString(ZaxSmsScheduler.count) };
    db.delete(table, whereClause, whereArgs);
    db.close();
    Log.d("MYAPP", "Entry deleted..");
    //sm.sendTextMessage(ZaxSmsScheduler.telno, null, ZaxSmsScheduler.msg, null, null);

}
```

I have set required permissions in my manifest and have registered my broadcast receiver. I kindly request you to provide your valuable suggestions to solve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use different notification id for multiple alarms

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
        String title = bundle.getString("title");
        String text = bundle.getString("text");
        String billno = bundle.getString("billno");
        int id = bundle.getInt("id");
        Toast.makeText(c, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final int NOTIF_ID = id;
        // final int NOTIF_ID = 1;
        NotificationManager notofManager = (NotificationManager) c
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(c, AyyappaGoldActivity.class);
        //notificationIntent.putExtra("billno", billno);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, title, when);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(c, title, text, contentIntent);

        //notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notofManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification);
    }

}
```

Code for setAlarm;

```
int NOTIF_ID = (int) cal.getTimeInMillis();
        NOTIF_ID++;
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("text", text);
        intent.putExtra("billno", billno);
        intent.putExtra("id", NOTIF_ID);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), NOTIF_ID, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent); // cancel any existing alarms

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```